# Caesars Cipher Free Code Camp challenge - Error return with 12 red dots

Tags: javascript

I am doing the Caesars Cipher challenge ON FREE CODE CAMP.
I believe my code should be working but I am getting an error I don't understand. I get 12 red dots. i Believe it has something to do with a null value. I use http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit and my array returns empty strings. I don't know why.

```
function rot13(str) { 
    //str = str.split('');
    var arr = [];
    // var regex = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str.charCodeAt(i) >= 65 && str.charCodeAt(i) <= 77) {
            arr.push(String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt[i] += 13));
        } else if(str.charCodeAt(i) >= 78 && str.charCodeAt(i) <= 90){
            arr.push(String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt[i] -= 13));
        } else if (str.charCodeAt(i) < 65){
            arr.push(str[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr.join('');
}
rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem just moments ago, I had the code right but I was getting that red dot. So I started testing and noticed that I had an empty string at the end of every array. Check out the array below.

```
["F", "R", "E", "E", " ", "C", "O", "D", "E", " ", "C", "A", "M", "P", " "]
```

So I just removed the empty string from the end and then it passed!

```
arr.splice(-1,1);

["F", "R", "E", "E", " ", "C", "O", "D", "E", " ", "C", "A", "M", "P"]
```